# Android The SSL connection could not be established

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

My Xamarin.Android project was working fine until today. Now my code is not working anymore:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://myapp.auth0.com/oauth/ro");
var request = new RestRequest();
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;            
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "some_json", ParameterType.RequestBody);
RestResponse response = await client.ExecutePostAsync(request);
Auth0Response auth0Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyAuth0Response>(response.Content);
```

The `response.Content` is null and the request returns an error message:

> The SSL connection could not be established

Inner exception:

> InnerException    {System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException:
> Authentication failed, see inner exception. --->
> Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000007d:SSL
> routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED} at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.c:1132

Inner message:

> Authentication failed, see inner exception.

Stack trace:

at Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsContext.ProcessHandshake () [0x00042] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/Mono.Btls/MonoBtlsContext.cs:220
at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status, System.Boolean renegotiate) [0x000da] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MobileAuthenticatedStream.cs:715
at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake(Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus,bool)
at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncHandshakeRequest.Run (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/AsyncProtocolRequest.cs:289
at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000fc] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/AsyncProtocolRequest.cs:223

Comment: Have you checked the SSL certificate from the browser? Maybe it's expired.

Comment: It is not. My iOS app is using the same url and it still works.

Comment: different OS have different standards about what security they require.  Is there a deeper inner exception message that you did not post?

Comment: I included the file name and line number in the inner exception, as well as the stack trace.

Comment: There could be many reasons as to why this would fail on your Android device. One reason could be an outdated version of Android where CA certs haven't been updated. Or time could be off. Check the inner exception, there is usually more info.

Comment: check this https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6351#issuecomment-945646088

Comment: I switched to using HttpClient and it's working again. I guess RestSharp is using some bad version of OpenSSL

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, app worked fine on IOS but showed this error on Android, so mislead..

Issue was the simplest. I'd installed my nice shiny new certificate on Apache server but had stupidly made SSLCertificateChainFile the certificate domain.net.crt where it should have been the root (digicert....crt).

Just maybe this will prevent one person chasing their tail (and question the validity of iPhone and even web - as i tested on chrome) as well - ssl auth process???)